Injecting values from middleware to page components in Nextjs
I am using Next 14 with App Router to build a small website project. One of the requirements is that the website has to have content in different languages. I saw that Nextjs documentation has a section about Internationalization, but I've decided to make things a little bit different.
I want to pass the list of translated words from the middleware to the page component. The middleware is identifying the language in the client and taking the dictionary of words accordingly. If the client's language is not supported then it falls back to a default language. Since I am working with a object that can become bigger with time I didn't want to use the params to inject this information in the page component. Instead, I created a class with a static variable that would hold this dictionary object.
I started making a Translation class that has static members like:
export class Translation {
    public static dictionary: Record<string, string>;

    public static getText(word: string): string {
        return Translation.dictionary[word] || word;
    }
}

Then, by using the middleware.ts I was intercepting the request and reading the Accept-Languages header to decide which dictionary I have to use in the Page. In order to pass this dictionary to the page I was setting the Translation.dictionary, which is a static variable, to the json that had all the translated words in the client's language:
...
import { Translation } from './translation';

import website_pt from "./locales/pt/website.json";
import website_en from "./locales/en/website.json";
import website_jp from "./locales/jp/website.json";

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const availableLocales = ["pt-BR", "ja", "en-US"];
    const defaultLocale = "pt-BR";
    const acceptLanguage = request.headers.get("accept-language")?.split(",");
    const clientLocale = acceptLanguage?.shift();

    const locale = availableLocales.find((locale: string): boolean => locale === clientLocale) || defaultLocale;

    const dictionaries: Record<string, Dictionary> = {
        "pt-BR": website_pt,
        "ja": website_jp,
        "en-US": website_en
    };
    
    Translation.dictionary = dictionaries[locale];
}

Finally, in the page I was accessing the Translation class to execute the translate method and render the translated words in the page:
import { Translation } from '../../translation';

export default function HomePage() {
    return (
        <div>
            {Translation.getText("Home")}
        </div>
    );
}

The thing is, the static variable dictionary in the Translation class is undefined when read by the page component, and I don't understand why.
I might solve this problem by doing the same way Next js Documentation is recomending to do it, but first I would like to understand why my previous solution didn't worked. And maybe learn if there are other ways to inject data from middleware to page without using the params or searchParams to do it.
